# How to call XSL template from java code?

Tags: java, xslt

How to call XSL template from java code ?

Please note that, I don't need to know how to transform xml docuemnt by XSL in Java.

What I need exactly is that, I have some XSLT document that contains a template that do something, ex:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Then I need that template to be called from java code. How to ??

Thanks All guyz, I did it, Please see :
http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-call-xslt-template-from-your.html

Comment: Yes, you do need to know how to transform XML document by XSL in Java, because that is how your template is to be called.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`javax.xml.transformer.Transformer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) API for this.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new File("c:/path/to/input.xml"));
Source xsl = new StreamSource(new File("c:/path/to/file.xsl"));
Result xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new File("c:/path/to/output.xml"));

try {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    // Handle.
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't transfer. It transforms one XML to other XML based on the given XSLT. That's where XSL is for. What exactly do you need after all? You should have elaborated that in your question. You can eventually change the XML source and/or the XML result.

Comment: Thanks, Please see the modified question above :)

Comment: You've edited your topicstart. Sorry, I still don't forsee any problems. Maybe you just want to save the result as HTML. Just change the file extension accordingly, e.g. `output.html`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's some code](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/java/news/javaxslt_0801.html) for a simple XSL transform, along with some tips for using XSL in Java.  And [here's another example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0407.html), complete with an example XML and XSL.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question that you have an XSLT which doesn't require an input document? Then just give the Transformer object some kind of minimal document:

transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<empty/>")), yourResult);

Comment: But the template requires some input, How to accomplish that?

Comment: That code does provide input. That string is a well-formed XML document. What happened when you tried it?